# calling something in a loop vs outside

Tags: java, string, for-loop, binary, system.out

Okay, so long problem short I am trying to convert a string of binary to the decimal that binary represents. I have a few print statements showing that the string is indeed a binary number and when I use my parse statement inside the loop it doesn't work, however, if I do the same exact statements on a different string with the same binary number it does work. The binary number in this example is 110 which should be 6. When I try to use the same string outside the loop it reverts back to null. Is there a way I can get it so when the string is changed in the loop statement I can use that new string outside the statement?

Inside the loop: result = "106"
outside the loop: result = "6"

If someone could explain whats happening that would be great.

```
 for(int i=inputs.length-1; i>inputs.length-1-k; i--)
            {

                String s = "" + inputs[i];
                //System.out.print(s);
                int decimalValue = Integer.parseInt(s, 2);
                System.out.print(decimalValue);

            }
    //      String blah = "110";
    //      int hah = Integer.parseInt(blah,2);
    //      System.out.println(hah);
```

Comment: The fact that you do `"" + inputs[i]` leads me to believe that `inputs` is *not* a `String[]`, so what is it? Or more on point: What is value of `s`? Did you try to print it too, so you can see what's going wrong?

Comment: Inputs is an array but when I print just the string s I get "106" which is the correct string of binary which is why Im confused. @Andreas

Comment: @suck_at_coding18 If `s = "106"`, then `parseInt(s, 2)` would throw exception, because `106` is *not* a binary string.

Comment: Im sorry my mistake I did not mean to say "106" I meant to say when I call the string s I get 110. Is this even the correct way to add to a string? It compiles and prints the string fine but I am not sure of any other way of adding something to an empty string. @Andreas

Comment: Why do you need that? I asked you what type `inputs` is, and you didn't answer that. Please read: [How to create a Minimal, **Complete**, and **Verifiable** example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You question is incomplete, because you don't show us what it is and what values it has. As such, it is not verifiable, because we can't reproduce the problem.

Comment: Inputs is of type Endpoint. A made up type in a different interface that this class inherits. This for-loop is scanning an array of endpoints that are 0's and 1's and giving me a binary number. Im trying to convert that binary number into a decimal number. @Andreas

Comment: Ok, so `"" + inputs[i]` is synonymous with `inputs[i].toString()`? If so, why not do that? --- Also, if you uncomment `System.out.print(s);`, and change both `print` to `println`, what do you see?

Comment: I see three different lines of 1-1-0 respectively. @Andreas

Comment: So, if you see `1`, then `1`, then `0`, then your code would be parsing those 3 binary strings, and since binary `1` is decimal `1`, and binary `0` is decimal `0`, your output would have been `110` before you changed `print` to `println`, so what is that `106` you mentioned? Again, please change your question to provide a **Complete** and **Verifiable** example.

Comment: The "106" was a typo Im not sure why I accidentally typed that. I will try to edit my question to make it more clear. @Andreas